# Is there a way to remove old files with a prefix in windows command line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to remove all files that have a prefix "tmp" that are older than 9 days. I've fond ways of doing one or the other but not both for some reason.

Comment: Can you describe what you have already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation found here they have these examples with Forfiles method :

```
Examples:

Delete all file with tmp in name if it is is 9 days old or older:
C:\> forfiles /m tmp*.* /c "cmd /c Del tmp*.* " /d -9
```

Answer (score 0):

**Be careful**, the following command may remove lot of files in a second!

```
del tmp*.*
```

`*` is wildcard for any character

`.*` is for any file extension

If you want to remove only such as `PDF` files, you can use

```
del tmp*.pdf
```

Then all `PDF` files whoes file name started with `tmp` will be removed.

Sure the command removes files in the current folder only. You can specify the file path together with the file name.